# Fragment instance is retained but child fragment is not re-attached

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

**Update:** accepted answer points to explanation (bug) with a work-around, but also see my Kotlin based work-around attached as an answer below.

This code is in Kotlin, but I think it is a basic android fragment life-cycle issue.

I have a Fragment that holds a reference to an other "subfragment"

Here is basically what I am doing:

1. I have a main fragment that has `retainInstance` set to true
2. I have a field in the main fragment that will hold a reference to the subfragment, initially this field is null
3. In the main fragment's `onCreateView`, I check to see if the subfragment field is null, if so, I create an instance of the subFragment and assign it to the field
4. Finally I add the subfragment to a container in the layout of the main fragment.
5. If the field is not null, ie we are in onCreateView due to a configuration change, I don't re-create the subfragment, I just try to added it to the containter.

When the device is rotated, I do observe the `onPaused()` and `onDestroyView()` methods of the subfragment being called, but I don't see any lifecyle methods being called on the subfragment during the process of adding the retained reference to the subfragment, to the child_container when the main fragments view is re-created.

The net affect is that I don't see the subfragment view in the main fragment.  If I comment out the if (subfragment == null) and just create a new subfragment everytime, i **do** see the subfragment in the view.

### Update

The answer below does point out a bug, in which the childFragmentManager is not retained on configuration changes.  This will ultimately break my intended usage, which was to preserve the backstack after rotation, however I think what I am seeing is something different.

I added code to the activities `onWindowFocusChanged` method and I see something like this when the app is first launched:

```
activity is in view
fm = FragmentManager{b13b9b18 in Tab1Fragment{b13b2b98}}
tab 1 fragments = [DefaultSubfragment{b13bb610 #0 id=0x7f0c0078}]
```

and then after rotation:

```
activity is in view
fm = FragmentManager{b13f9c30 in Tab1Fragment{b13b2b98}}
tab 1 fragments = null
```

here fm is the childFragmentManager, and as you can see, we still have the same instance of Tab1Fragment, but it has a new childFragmentManager, which I think is unwanted and due to the bug reported in the answer below.
The thing is that I **did** add the subfragment to this **new** childFragmentManger.
So it seems like the transaction never executes with the reference to the fragment that was retained,  but does complete if I create a brand new fragment. (I did try calling `executePendingTransactions` on the new childFragmentManager)

---

```
class Tab1Fragment: Fragment() {

    var subfragment: DefaultSubfragment? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        if (subfragment == null ) {
            subfragment = DefaultSubfragment()
            subfragment!!.sectionLabel = "label 1"
            subfragment!!.buttonText = "button 1"
        }
        addRootContentToContainer(R.id.child_container, content = subfragment!!)

    return rootView
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

inline fun Fragment.addRootContentToContainer(containerId: Int, content: Fragment) {
    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(containerId, content)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem looks similar to the issue described here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222

unfortunately this issue will probably not be fixed by google.

Using retained fragments for UI or nested fragments is not a good idea - they are recomended to be used in place of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance, so ie. for large collections/data structures. Also you could find Loaders better than retained fragments, they also are retained during config changes.

btw. I find retained fragments more of a hack - like using `android:configChanges` to "fix" problems caused by screen rotations. It all works until user presses home screen and android decides to kill your app process. Once user will like to go back to your app - your retained fragments will be destroyed - and you will still have to recreate it. So its always better to code everything like if your resources could be destroyed any time.

Comment: I will take a closer look at the link you posted.  I am not 100% sure this is the same issue I am having.  BTW, all I am really trying to do is have several tabs, and each tab have it's own backstack.  I have seen a lot of solutions that involve managing your own back stack,  but they were kind of old, and for the most part I think the nested fragments seem to be working (each tab has it's own childFragmentManager with it's own back stack), now is the trick part of handing device rotations.

Comment: I am going to unaccept this for now, I do see the bug, and ultimately it will prevent me from doing what I was planning,  but this __seems__ to be something different.  I will add more to my question

Comment: the issue I was having __is__ related to this bug.  I will add some ore info in my question to document what I found, but basically this "subfragment" still thinks it is part of the now dead activity.  Explicitly removing it from the activity before it is destroyed, then allows it to be added to the new activity created after the rotation.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer to my question above points out a reported bug in the support library v4 in which nested fragments (and child fragment managers) are no longer retained on configuration changes.

One of the [posts](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74222#c45) provides a work-around (which seems to work well).
The work around involves creating a subclass of Fragment and uses reflection.

Since my original question used Kotlin code, I thought I would share my Kotlin version of the work around here in case anyone else hits this.  In the end, I am not sure I will stick with this solution, since it is still somewhat of a hack, it still manipulates private fields, however if the field name is changed, the error will be found at compile time rather than runtime.

The way this works is this:

1. In your fragment that will contain child fragments you create a field retainedChildFragmentManager, that will hold the childFragmentManager that will be lost during the configuration change
2. In the onCreate callback for the same fragment, you set retainInstance to true
3. In the onAttach callback for the same fragment, you check to see if retainedChildFragmentManger is non-null, if so you call a Fragment extension function that re-attaches the retainedChildFragmentManager, otherwise you set the retainedChildFragmentManager to the current childFragmentManager.
4. Finally you need to fix the child fragments to point back to the newly created hosting activity (the bug leaves them referencing the old activity, which I think results in a memory leak).

Here is an example:

### Kotlin Fragment extensions

```
// some convenience functions
inline fun Fragment.pushContentIntoContainer(containerId: Int, content: Fragment) {
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(containerId, content)
    transaction.addToBackStack("tag")
    transaction.commit()

}
 inline fun Fragment.addRootContentToContainer(containerId: Int, content: Fragment) {

    val transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(containerId, content)
    transaction.commit()
}

// here we address the bug
inline fun Fragment.reattachRetainedChildFragmentManager(childFragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
    setChildFragmentManager(childFragmentManager)
    updateChildFragmentsHost()
}

fun Fragment.setChildFragmentManager(childFragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
     if (childFragmentManager is FragmentManagerImpl) {
         mChildFragmentManager = childFragmentManager   // mChildFragmentManager is private to Fragment, but the extension can touch it
     }
}

fun Fragment.updateChildFragmentsHost() {
    mChildFragmentManager.fragments.forEach { fragment ->  // fragments is hidden in Fragment
        fragment?.mHost = mHost  // mHost is private also
    }
}
```

### The Fragment Hosting the child Fragments

```
class Tab1Fragment : Fragment() , TabRootFragment {

    var subfragment: DefaultSubfragment? = null
    var retainedChildFragmentManager: FragmentManager? = null
    override val title = "Tab 1"

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        if (subfragment == null ) {
            subfragment = DefaultSubfragment()
            subfragment!!.sectionLable = "label 1x"
            subfragment!!.buttonText = "button 1"
            addRootContentToContainer(R.id.child_container, content = subfragment!!)
        }
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (retainedChildFragmentManager != null) {
            reattachRetainedChildFragmentManager(retainedChildFragmentManager!!)
        } else {
            retainedChildFragmentManager = childFragmentManager
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }    
}
```

Comment: This no longer works in newer APIs / Kotling versions (1.4.10+). Does not compile.